# trying to call functions asynchronously in javascript (with angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, voice-recognition, q

I'm trying to call a function (for TTS) in phonegap that varies in length (i'm reading different news headlines) immediately following each headline, I have a voice recognition function, prompting the user for a voice command. like this...

```
navigator.tts.speak("If you would like to go to the next article, please say continue. Otherwise, say read me for another section"); 
$scope.reco();
```

The `reco()` calls voice recognition. I cannot get the previous call

```
navigator.tts.speak(*<news_headline.>*)
```

to finish before `reco()` is called. I am using angular, so I've tried using angular's promises ($q) (in a few different ways), but I can't seem to figure out how to get `speak()` to wait before `reco()` is called. Any suggestions?

One more dimension: I am using phonegap (almost entirely for android purposes), and in my little experience, it can cause a lot of trouble.
Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: does `speak` have a completion callback? If so would run your code there

Comment: +1 to charlietfl. Check is there is a .success(function()) or .then(function()) on .speak(); If not, we get our hands dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the documentation for both TTS plugins listed on build.phonegap.com and both have callback functionality.

Try this:

```
navigator.tts.speak("If you would like to go to the next article, please say continue. Otherwise, say read me for another section",$scope.reco);
```

Comment: i tried using callbacks `navigator.tts.speak("text",function(){ $scope.reco;}, function(){ alert("fail")});` and it didn't work for me (still ran asynchronously) i'll check again though..

Comment: yeah seems to be an issue with the `navigator.tts` API as it would have to provide something like a promise or a callback that gets invoked when its finished, otherwise theres nothing you can do do to ensure its finished before the next bit of code runs